# Distribution of log-log linear regression

Tags: logarithms, normal-distribution, regression

Edit: Sorry yeah not too clear, probably posted this too late at night...

Essentially I have data which appears to be in exponential form - a log-log graph put it close to a straight line. Using R, I fit it using `lm(log(y)~log(x))` which gave good estimates for $a$ and $b$ with a high $R^2$ value and the estimated equation following the shape of the data points.

My question is would Y still follow a normal distribution as if I had used `lm(y~x)`? Unless I'm seriously mixing things up, in this case $Y\sim N(aX+b,\sigma^2)$ so would this still be the case after log-transforming x and y?

Thanks

Comment: Without more information, there's no reason to believe that the error or $Y$ should follow a particular distribution.

Comment: Perhaps the question can be interpreted as follows. If $Y$ is a random variable such that $\log Y=\log\tilde y+E$ where $\tilde y$ is constant and $E$ is normally distributed with zero mean, what is the distribution of $Y-\tilde y$?

Comment: Sorry, edited it to try and make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have estimated the coefficients of the regression by minimizing the squared distances. The error would be normal as usual.

Think like this, you have transformed the data by taking logarithm (assuming all data points are positive here), and you presumed that error would be log-normal. But if this is the case the error would always be positive. Which is not possible. Because as you know from the one of the assumptions that you take when doing linear regression (OLS), is all the errors sum up to zero.

Distribution of $Y$ would change. Without much thinking you can say that because you have changed the domain of $Y$ as well as the mean and the variance of the distribution. Intuitively speaking, by taking the $log$, you have squeezed the domain (e.g. what was $Y$= 100 then, is $log(100)=2$ now. So you can see you changed the distribution function to somewhat having "peakedness", "spiky"! This happens because the integration over the entire domain must sum to 1, as you have contracted the domain, so you have to lump your probability mass over smaller length compared to before.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get what you're saying about it changing the shape  however would it also change the distribution of the data? Ie would y  be normally distributed or would it be something different ( and if so  what?)? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The "Basic" distribution would stay the same! Say for $Y = 3$, the event in the sample space that generates $Y=3$, would also generate $Y = log(3)$. You can think of them as random variables, and the value a random variable takes depends upon which event in the sample space has occurred.